# pandas multiindex averaging and grouping

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have created a nested dictionary of my data, which would like to convert to a pandas dataframe and use it to later average certain subsets of the data.

In short, I started with an empty dictionary

```
scores = {}
```

and then populated it by looping over 4 categories

```
scores[(subdir, method, time, 'nMI')].append(nMItemp)
```

which I converted into a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(scores)
```

and this looks like this

[image]

What I would like to do now, e.g., is to average all data 'nMI', line-by-line across the categories '0.316228   0.562341    1.000000    1.778279    3.162278 ... '  within the parentgroups 'mu_0.2' and 'modularity_signed'.

Could someone explain how to do this? If this datastructure is not the best way to do this, could you suggest a better one?

Comment: You mean create an extra column with the average values of all `nMI` columns only?

Comment: Yes, or just return those values. To be more precise, I just want to average only within certain parent categories 'mu_0.2' and 'modularity_signed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return specific columns on a multiindex, then you can use `.loc`. I believe this might do the trick. Once you have selected the columns you want, you can perform `.mean()`. Pitifully I cannot generate something that matches your data. If you could provide some example data with the same structure, I can fit my example to your case:

```
df_output = df.loc[:,('mu_0.2','modularity_signed',slice(None),'nMI')]
```

An example can be seen here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
print(df)
print(df.loc[:,(('bar','foo'),'one')])
```

Original dataframe:

```
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A      -0.025131 -2.455114 -0.558735 -0.235553  0.250540 -1.444213  1.030049 -1.642283
B       0.558622 -1.304947 -0.457322 -1.726946  0.184681 -0.240676 -0.890618 -0.192366
C       0.345557 -0.339904  1.114021 -0.636077 -0.187887  0.472014 -0.540658 -0.527172
```

After filtering with `.loc`:

```
first        bar       foo
second       one       one
A      -0.025131  0.250540
B       0.558622  0.184681
C       0.345557 -0.187887
```